# Why is it impossible to initialize a constant variable after its declaration?

Tags: c

This is not a problem, but I'd like to understand the following behaviour:

```
int main() {
    // This does not work
    int const a;
    a = 50;

    // This work
    int const a = 50;
}
```

Why does the compiler throw the following error:

> main.c:4:7: error: assignment of read-only variable ‘a’

I don't understand why even the initialization is forbidden. The line 3 has no translation in the assembly language. Does the compiler not detect that the line 4 is the first affectation (translation issue: I meant "assignment")?

EDIT: Ok, so let's say this is how the C language is. But this can be a problem because when I use C89, the declarations must be at the top of the functions and I can't use constant variables because assignments must be placed after the declarations . The only solution is to declare non-const variables or initialize all the variables. I find this "dirty".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > " Does the compiler not detect that the line 4 is the first affectation?"

It could, in this simple case. However the rules are written to cover all cases of initialization. 
Compiler looks at one file at a time. A program may be composed of many files. The language allows variables to be declared in one translation unit (file) and used in another.
The rules are written so they take care of all such cases

Answer (score 6):

> I don't understand why even the initialization is forbidden.

The key is in the error message:

> error: assignment of read-only variable ‘a’

It isn't an *initialization*, it is an *assignment*. An assignment modifies an existing object, and that is not permitted if said object is `const`.

This, on the other hand, despite using the `=` syntax, *is* an initialization:

```
int const a = 50;
```

Comment: @MattTaylor Does it really? I thought it would be unspecified.

Comment: @MattTaylor I think it depends on your compiler. Some would just leave an int in the memory with junk value and read-only permission, I think

Comment: Really? My boss insists that it's UB to read the uninitialised number.

Comment: @CIsForCookies Well, what really matters is what the language spec has to say about it, and I am pretty sure it is unspecified (whether reading from it is UB or unspecified is one of those things where C differs slightly from C++, so I am not entirely sure.)

Comment: @juanchopanza I thought that what I wrote is a kind of an unspecified, isn't it?

Comment: @CIsForCookies Not really, because it can depend on more than the compiler.

Comment: Hi juanchopanza, can you explain why `const int *b; b = &a;` is not forbidden? (pointer types instead of data types)

Comment: @AlterMann Because that is a non-const pointer to `const int`. So you can change the pointer, but not modify the thing it points to via said pointer.

Comment: @P45Imminent: 6.7.8 Initialization > Semantics 10: _"If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly,
then: if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer; if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;"_ `int const a;` <-- implied `auto` storage, so as far as the standard is concerned, `a` needn't be initialized to `0`

Comment: So @MattTaylor: `a` needn't be 0 in this particular case. However, if you write `static int a;`, `a` will be initialized to `0`

Comment: also if it were global it would be 0.... but it isn't very valuable to a program to have a uninitialized constant value... you are either giving a name to a 0 or an indeterminate garbage value...

Answer (score 5):

Because it's a constant!

`a = 50;` is an assignment, not an initialisation.

`int const a;` essentially sets `a` to an indeterminant value (which you should never read by the way). Perhaps your compiler will warn you of this if you ask it nicely.